# Script for making the field required in Jira create issue screen on the basis of Radio checks?

Tags: javascript, groovy, jira

How can i make the fields Require dynamical on the basis of the radio checks, means if i select the option A then few custom fields should changed to require even if they are optional
from the field configuration. or is their any way to do it with the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [plugin Behaviours](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.plugin.Behaviours), using it you can do something like:

```
FormField dropdown = getFieldByName("My Radio Check")
FormField other= getFieldByName("Other field")

if (dropdown.getFormValue() == 'A') {
     other.setHidden(false) // set custom filed vlaues
     other.setFormValue("A choosen")
     other.setRequired(true)
} else {
     other.setHidden(true) // hide any fields you like
     other.setRequired(false)
}
```

check the [documentation](https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JBHV/JIRA+Behaviours+Plugin) for more info.